# Tensorflow: How to feed a Tensor to a trained neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I cant get my trained neural network to work.
I want to feed a numpy array (essentially a picture) to my trained network.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(graph_path, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('y_pred:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

I always get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'DecodeJpeg/contents', does not exist in the graph.

I have tried many different keys for that feed-dict, but i cant get it right.
I trained the network with the dataset-api, that means I dont have any tf.placeholder i can fill. Instead the network is beeing feed through an iterator over the dataset which contains tensor objects. The tfrecord file was created using [this script](https://www.paste.org/93850) from google

Start of my model function:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["image"], [-1, _DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE, _DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
```

Excerpt from the end:

```
predictions = {
    # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
    # `logging_hook`.
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="y_pred")
}
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

# Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=2)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
```

This is the [Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znYYR.png)

How can I get those predictions / how can I feed an image to the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a name to your input layer, retrieve it by name like you do for the softmax tensor and then feed it your numpy array. Here is what it looks like :

```
# First, name your input tensor
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["image"], [-1, _DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE, _DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE, 3], name='input_layer')

...

predictions = sess.run('y_pred:0',
                       {'input_layer:0': image_data})
```

This should work as long as image_data's shape is [1, _DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE, _DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE, 3]

The explanation as of why you can't access the DecodedJpeg tensors by name is that tf.Dataset operators are not in the main graph.

Comment: Since your model expect batches of various sizes, when you're feeding it with a single image, it throws an error. A simple workaround is to add a dimension to your image. Try : image_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, 0)

Comment: it is, thank you very much. The values are not satisfactory, but thats another problem.
+1

Answer (score 0):

`image_data` is expected to be a tensor. You can read jpeg image as a tensor using below snippet (`image_file` is location of jpeg file)

```
# decode the JPEG image as tensor
image_data = tf.cast(tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file), tf.float32)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but if I do this i get this Error:

TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.For reference, the tensor object was Tensor("Cast:0", shape=(?, ?, ?), dtype=float32) which was passed to the feed with key input_layer:0.

Comment: image_data should not be a tensor at all. If you want to use decode_jpeg, you should first eval the tensor it returns, then feed the value to input_layer.